# make ListView Scrollbar difference and more useful

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar

i have seen a lot of android apps those have a ListView that some differences with my ListViews. in theire ListView Scroll bar seen like this:

[image]

in picture above when you scroll your list that scroll bar will be shown and u can touch on it and scroll easier.

but in my app seen like this:

[image]

this is my layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/do"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background"

        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

i had googled many times but i didnt find any trick. can anybody help me how i can make my scroll like picture one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add these lines in your listview. It worked for me.

```
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbars="none
```

Answer (score 3):

set `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` in properties of the listview.
Also if you want fast scroll thumb to be visible always, set         `android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"`

then, in your xml definition of the listview, you would have something like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: @aTa also add android:scrollbars="none" (as suggested below) and see if it works. And it is better to post your layout xml file here, so we can check it to detect the problematic properties.

Comment: thank uuuuuu yrajabi. your code works ok. the promblem was in my theme :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Hi Use This attribute in your ListView which you declare in you layout file.

android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: can you explain what you want once again.